# Python Selenium does not update html after a Javascript execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing out the code below to scrape some [Options data](https://marketchameleon.com/Screeners/Options) from Marketchameleon.com. The original table is sorted by ATM IV % Change, however I would like to sort it by Implied Straddle Premium column. As it is not a button to click I though about (after checking the HTML source) doing it like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get("https://marketchameleon.com/Screeners/Options")    
bs_obj = BSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser').encode("utf-8")
with open("Market_Chameleon_Unsorted.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(bs_obj))
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//th[@aria-label='Implied StraddlePremium %: activate to sort column ascending']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-label','Implied StraddlePremium %: activate to sort column descending')", element)
bs_obj = BSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser').encode("utf-8")
with open("Market_Chameleon_Sorted.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(bs_obj))
```

The code runs without any errors, but it does not sort the table, i.e the unsorted and the sorted one are the same (I parse the HTML files in R). It seems the page does not really refresh after the html is modified by javascript. If I do a normal refresh, I again get the original html with the unsorted table. How can I explain Selenium to sort the table? Is there another way?

Comment: You have to go deeper. Changing the attribute on the `<th>` isn't enough; it probably has no effect at all, depending on how the JS was written. Generally, changing the html itself wont trigger JS at all. You could try looking at the JS in the page, finding what functions are called to perform the sorting.

Comment: Instead of updating HTML, try to click required table header to change soritng

Comment: Thank you, @Anderson, clicking actually did the trick..for some reason I though I have to click the small triangle without any tag.